# Why is ZSH shell not changing the prompt?

Tags: unix, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I was using bash before switching to zsh.

On my `~/.zsh` I have `export PS1="\w ~ "`, but it is not making those changes to reflect the prompt. I want my prompt to show something like `Documents/Rails_App/views ~`

I have opened a new tab and closed re-opened the app.

Comment: the dbl-quotes allow for expansion when the `export` command is executed, so you prompt no longer holds the `\w` string, but the value of the `\w` string at the time the `export` line was executed. Try using `export PS1='\w ~ '`. Good luck.

Comment: also  the file that is autoloaded is ~/.zshrc not ~/.zsh

Comment: Both of you are correct.

Answer (score 8):

The first level prompt of *Zsh* can be set in with either `PROMPT`, `prompt` or `PS1`.

*Zsh* uses other escapes than *Bash*. Most notably do they start with `%` not `\`. The equivalent to *Bash's* `\w` would be `%~`.

So just putting setting the following line in your `~/.zshrc` should do the trick:

```
PROMPT='%~ ~'
```

*Note*: There is (usually) no need to `export PROMPT` in *Zsh* - or *Bash* for that matter.

---

If it does not work for you, it most likely has to do with *Oh-My-Zsh* as it already provides its own settings for `PROMPT`. So you have to make sure that you set `PROMPT` after *Oh-My-Zsh* has been sourced.

If you used the template that came with *Oh-My-Zsh* it should be after this line:

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that I was historically using `~/.zprofile` instead of  `~/.zshrc`, which should be ~equivalent on Mac as Terminal is a login shell, but `PROMPT` variable was getting either ignored or overriden. Once I moved it to `~/.zshrc`, it worked. Content of `~/.zshrc` for the reference:

```
PROMPT='%F{yellow}%n@%m: %F{white}[%T] %F{cyan}%1d $ %F{reset}'
```

Comment: great! Now if only someone would explain why (not through a new question, pretty please; just add a few words right in this answer).

Answer (score 3):

On Debian distro.

After installing *zsh* from standard source `apt install zsh` comment `#prompt adam1` inside `.zshrc` file and reload settings `source ~/.zshrc`.

Now add custom prompt: `PROMPT='Greetings %n '`

Image: [zsh custom prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUTyk.png)

Comment: Do not add images/screenshots of code. Directly format the code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `_PROMPT` in zsh:

```
export _PROMPT='%d ~ '
```

Comment: Nope. Still not desired output.